# While loop won't break in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, while-loop, multiprocessing

As I received no feedback, yet, for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721716/check-if-subprocess-breaks-and-restart-if-true), I re-conceptualize (and simplify) the problem here. In this simplified case I'm wondering how I can restart a while loop that won't break in a multiprocessing queue.

I want to run a function on several cores using the `multiprocessing` library.

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)                     # Start a pool with 5 cores
analysis = p.map(function_to_call,'abcdefghij') # Call function_to_call on every core 
                                                # each time with a different letter from
                                                # string 'abcdefghij' and collect results
print(analysis)

def function_to_call(arg):
    result = []
    time = timeit.default_timer()               # timeit library needed
    time_even = int(str(time)[-1])              # get last number of time
########## below can't be changed ###########
    while True:
        if (time_even % 2) == 0:                # if last number is even, do stuff
            result.append('problem')
        else:                                   # else append arg to result
            result.append(str(arg))
            break 
########## above can't be changed ###########
    print(result) 
    return(result)                              # and return result
```

The result will be always different with respect to when the script is compiled. In my case, the output in the terminal is:

```
['b']
['c']
['g']
['h']
['i']
['e']  # <--- note that the process run in parallel and not serial
```

The conclusion is that the function call gets stucked in the while loop when it's called with the arguments `'a'`, `'d'`, `'f'`, and `'j'` (because the last number of the timestamp is obviously even in those cases). However, if I add `and False` to the if-statement in the while loop so that it always breaks, the following is printed to the terminal, indicating that everything is working perfectly fine (print(result) is compiled):

```
['a']
['b']
['d']
['c']
['g']
['h']
['f']
['j']
['i']
['e']
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['j']]
```

In the script I'm working on it can happen that the function_to_call does not return an output in some cases. However, rerunning the function several times will output a result in the end (which I wanted to imitate with the timestamp). Therefore, I would like to adapt my script so that function_to_call is called with the same argument when it does not return an output.

Unfortunately, the function I want to call takes several hours to come to an end. So I don't want to force it to break after some preset time value.
I'll be thankful for every comment and all suggestions!

Comment: So you can't tell if after waiting infinity amount of time the function will eventually deliver an result.

Comment: In your `while True` loop, `time_even` is never re-computed. So if it is not an even number the first time around, it will never be and the `result` list will keep growing.

Comment: @Lee: I can tell! However, I guess it will take several days until I can tell

Comment: @Booboo: exactly, it is only recalculated if ```fuction_to_call``` is called again

Comment: There is a distinction between calling a function that takes several hours to complete versus your simulation loop. In the latter case you could have been passed for example a Semaphore as an additional argument then in each loop iteration it could test it and break depending upon whether could conditionally acquire it. But in the case of the long running function, you may have no such control over its workings.

Comment: When function_to_call is executed with same value how likely is it to take days to completion again?

Comment: @Booboo No, I have not such control. What I do in the actual script is in my other, [more complex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721716/check-if-subprocess-breaks-and-restart-if-true), i.e. the part where I set ```frog``` and call ```frog.process```

Comment: @Lee It takes days everytime. However, if the function call works, it starts to incrementally gather the output after a few seconds, but unfortunately I don't know where the output is collected

Answer (score 0):

Re-run it with an exponentially increasing timeout:

```
from stopit import ThreadingTimeout
timeout = 3600 # should probably be set slightly above the expected runtime
while True:
    with ThreadingTimeout(timeout) as timeout_ctx:
        result = function_to_call()
    if timeout_ctx.state != timeout_ctx.TIMED_OUT:
        return result
    timeout *= 2
```

This way you are certain you won't do more than twice too much work, in average.

NB: I use in my example the stopit library https://github.com/glenfant/stopit

Comment: Maybe that works. However, it is unclear to me how result_or_timeout would look like

Comment: Added a link to a neat library for running code with timeout

Comment: thx for updating the code. Unfortunately, I don't know what ```Timeout``` (with capital T) and the error "name 'Timeout' is not defined" is printed to the screen